# Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined in WHERE

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query as shown below in which at `Line A` I am using `$cond`.

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT
    hello_world.firstname,
    hello_world.surname,
    good_morning.fname
FROM
    hello_world INNER JOIN good_morning
ON  hello_world.no = good_morning.no
WHERE hello_world.$cond AND good_morning.fpath IS NOT NULL           // Line A
```

The value of `$cond` will be different in different scenarios:

**Case 1:** The value `$cond` is

```
NO = 'ABC-12820' AND SPECIFIC_ID = 1 AND ISSUE = 'FINAL' AND VOLUME = 'J'.
```

**Case 2:** The value of `$cond` is

```
NO = 'ABC-12820'.
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I need to make at `Line A` in the **SQL query** above so that `Line A` behaves like this:

```
SELECT
    hello_world.firstname,
    hello_world.surname,
    good_morning.fname
FROM
    hello_world INNER JOIN good_morning
ON  hello_world.no = good_morning.no
WHERE hello_world.NO = 'ABC-12820'
  AND hello_world.SPECIFIC_ID = 1
  AND hello_world.VOLUME = 'J'
  AND good_morning.fpath IS NOT NULL           // Line A
```

Comment: @Tushar, your edit introduced a syntax error. `ANhello_world`. Now corrected.

Comment: Thanks for correcting it. Apologies for mistake and not paying proper attention after formatting code. <You are a Life Saver> :)

Comment: If a column name appears in more than one table referenced in the SQL statement then that column needs to be prefixed with the relevant table name (or its alias). So you would need to edit the $cond string to reflect this